# Multithreading - why working on a reference doesn't change it, while on a pointer works properly

Tags: c++, multithreading

Can anybody explain me why

```
void doSomething(vector<int>& vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        vec.push_back(i);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> v;
    thread t1(doSomething, v);
    thread t2(doSomething, v);
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints 0, while the same thing with a pointer prints 200

```
void doSomething(vector<int>* vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        vec->push_back(i);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int>* v = new vector<int>();
    thread t1(doSomething, v);
    thread t2(doSomething, v);
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
    cout << v->size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't working on a reference be equal (to working on a pointer) here?

Edit: it's not thread-safe on purpose

Can you provide me with a reference as to why do I need to use std::ref?

Comment: You are lucky that you get anything at all. You have two threads, one vector and no locking. Anything could happen.

Comment: @ZanLynx with the pointer version, absolutely. with the reference version it's actually quite safe, if not what the OP expected, as explained in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @aruisdante: True. If it worked like mewa expected it would have the same problem.

Comment: @ZanLynx I did it on purpose, I was trying to see what can happen when concurrent modifications occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Your code is **not** thread safe (concurrent `push_back` on a vector)

**2)** Arguments are passed by value by default to [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). This semantic of copying the arguments is natural with threads : any argument will be copied/moved to thread-accessible storage. Doing so, the `std:::thread` does its best to avoid concurrency access to shared objects.

Use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to pass an argument by reference to your thread callable :

```
thread t1(doSomething, std::ref(v));
thread t2(doSomething, std::ref(v));
                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Without `std::ref`, neither gcc or clang compile this code.

---

For future reference, `std::thread` constructors are described in section § 30.3.1.2 of the C++ standard.

Comment: Could you post a reference with explanation why? Also, it made it with msvc

Comment: @mewa there's an explanation in the links in this answer. Both `code highlighs` before the main snipper are links to the respective templates. Check the constructor of `std::thread` for the reference

Comment: Yes. I also edited to explain a little more. basically, `std::thread` use copy semantics on the argument to avoid (by default) working on shared objects.

Answer (score 1):

std::thread unfortunately takes parameters by value. Even if you set it up to take by reference, it still ends up copying it. You can use std::ref to pass by reference.